# Mouse Over Effects for Button in C# (using Visual Studio 05)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to change the background image based on mouseenter and mouseleave events to achieve a mouseover effect for the buttons. What is the simplest way of achieving this (preferably in a manner so that the button can be inherited)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
this.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile("file1");       
}

private void Form1_MouseEnter(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
this.BackgroundImage=Image.FromFile("file2");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for showing how to load images from file. I am new to VC# so wasn't sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class, inheriting from Button, and override [`OnMouseEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseenter.aspx) and [`OnMouseLeave`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmouseleave.aspx). Give it a property so that you can set which background image it should get when the mouse enters, and you are good to go.

Full working example (with a couple of design-time support attributes added):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class HighlightButton : Button
    {
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [Description("The background image that the Button should have when the mouse is over a visible part of it.")]
        public Image MouseoverBackgroundImage { get; set; }
        // property to hold the original background image while the mouse-over
        // image is displayed, so that we can restore it when the mouse leaves
        protected Image OriginalBackgroundImage { get; set; }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.OriginalBackgroundImage = this.BackgroundImage;
            this.BackgroundImage = this.MouseoverBackgroundImage;
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BackgroundImage = this.OriginalBackgroundImage;
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: realized that my initial sample changed the BackColor, not the BackgroundImage. Fixed that.